# Is there an existing piece of software that allows you to (easily) build queries throught a webpage?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, interface

I would like to build arbitrary queries to a database, by allowing the user to build queries "on the fly". For every object/table, being able to select its attributes, and then "building" the query (that would translate into a SQL statement) and finally launching it, all through a web interface.
The ticketing system "rt" does that, for example, and another example would be the http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx  webpage.

I'm currently programming in rails but any existing solution that implements this (or something similar) would be welcome.

Comment: Beware of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful when creating dynamically generated queries like this that will need to be executed via sp_executesql (example: ms sql server), etc..... make sure you cover all of your bases to ensure that your application isnt vulnerable to SQL injection attacks as this type of development will essentially get one in a lot of trouble if its done incorrectly.. I would recommend storing all queries in a table and only reading queries from this table to help isolate the queries that are being ran in your application. Just identify them with a label, and allow the EU to choose the label from a dropdown list control on the frontend.

Good luck and I'm not sure of any software that will help assist

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your use case is here but i would say check out the

[Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) ( Object Relational Mapper )

**Edit
After reading more and looking at the example. I would only suggest Doctrine for a large website.

Then use Doctrines DQL syntax with some javascript/jquery magic for the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the queries you're referencing aren't arbitrary: they're on a very specific problem domain, on a specific set of sql tables.

That said, if I were you I'd look into how people are building sql queries with javascript. Something like these:

http://code.google.com/p/django-querybuilder/

http://css.dzone.com/articles/sqlike-sql-querying-engine?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fria+(RIA+Zone)

http://thechangelog.com/post/4914956307/rel-arel-ported-to-node-js-with-some-changes

That'll at least get you a good idea of the underlying data structures.

Comment: And then I'd store the generated json in something like MongoDB or PostgresQL's hstore http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html if you can. That way you don't have to do as much conversion back and forth.